# More detailed session duration statistics for sessions with length over 1800 seconds

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics, under Audience/Behavior/Engagement, I get a report like:

```
# Engagement
# 20150401-20160531
# ----------------------------------------

Session Duration,Sessions,Pageviews
0-10 seconds,"9,290,400","9,663,181"
11-30 seconds,"601,423","1,463,176"
31-60 seconds,"561,265","1,659,405"
61-180 seconds,"1,268,538","5,186,257"
181-600 seconds,"1,354,948","9,322,461"
601-1800 seconds,"626,035","5,969,774"
1801+ seconds,"83,676","1,601,572"
,"13,786,285","34,865,826"
```

Showing session length vs number of sessions.

Question:

- I would like to see more details in the 1801+ seconds group, for instance in half-hour intervals up to two hours, i.e. 1801-3600 seconds, 3601-5400 seconds, 5401-7200 seconds, 7201+ seconds
- Is there some way to get this data out of GA? Either using the web UI or the API?

### Update

I did as @J_Brazier suggested and created a segment:

[image: segment definition]

I do not understand the results when I add this segment to the report. How can the number of sessions of duration 0-10 seconds be anything but zero for users with session length >= 1801?

[image: report with new segment added]

## Update 2

I got it to work (I believe), by creating segment definitions like the following:

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Comment: don't segment on users - segment on sessions. Segmenting on users includes all sessions that the user had, not just the one matching the pattern.

Comment: OK and how do I segment on sessions?

Comment: I believe I figured it out, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a segment that identifies this group, like so:

[image: 60 second segment]

EDIT: The issue you are encountering is that this segment here filters Users. Each User may have multiple Sessions, so any User with one session of at least 60 seconds (in this case) will have all of their Sessions included. If this is an issue, your own solution is exactly what I would use.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, and have a follow-up question that I have updated the question with.

Comment: @codeape Ah, I've updated my answer. I was isolating Users who had had a single Session that was long enough, whereas it seems you wanted to only measure the seconds of that length.